# Search query for my most visited sites or sites where I have contribute rights

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, search, content-search-web-part

I am adding a content search webpart on my SharePoint online startpage where I want to show the sites that I am visiting the most. I have this as my query

```
ContentClass=urn:contentclass:{User.Name}
```

What this do is give me sites where I have altered content in pages. uploading and changing documents in document libraries has no effect.

Is there a way I can query sites where I have edit permissions?
is there a way I can query sites that I visited the most?